# How to exclude a class in an ArchUnit rule?

Tags: java, unit-testing, archunit

While creating a rule for a layered architecture in ArchUnit, it's not clear to me how to exclude a single class (Main).
[The base example](https://github.com/TNG/ArchUnit-Examples/blob/master/example-plain/src/test/java/com/tngtech/archunit/exampletest/LayeredArchitectureTest.java#L41) excludes with a source and a target.

... but I don't get how it converts to my need. I just want just Main to be ignored. Why? Because Main references all layers since it injects all dependencies in place.

[The original code is in my GitHub](https://github.com/lsoares/clean-architecture-sample) [along with the failing test](https://github.com/lsoares/clean-architecture-sample/blob/master/src/test/kotlin/users/architecture/Layers.kt#L20). (the project is a dummy one so it's straightforward to run; just clone it, run the tests and see one failing).

Answer (score 8):

Consider you have imported all your classes:

```
JavaClasses classes = new ClassFileImporter().importPackages("org.example");
```

Then you typically check all these classes against an ArchRule, no matter if it's a class rule or an architecture rule:

```
ArchRule rule = classes()
    .that().areAnnotatedWith(Service.class)
    .should().haveSimpleNameEndingWith("Service");

rule.check(classes);
```

To exclude classes from the rule, you could filter `classes` and pass the filtered `JavaClasses` to the rule:

```
import static com.tngtech.archunit.base.DescribedPredicate.not;
import static com.tngtech.archunit.core.domain.JavaClass.Predicates.equivalentTo;
import static com.tngtech.archunit.lang.conditions.ArchPredicates.are;

JavaClasses allExceptMain = classes.that(are(not(equivalentTo(Main.class))));
rule.check(allExceptMain);
```

To exclude the class `Main` and all classes that are defined inside of `Main` (inner classes, anonymous classes, lambdas etc.) you could adjust the filter:

```
import static com.tngtech.archunit.base.DescribedPredicate.not;
import static com.tngtech.archunit.core.domain.JavaClass.Predicates.belongToAnyOf;

JavaClasses allExceptMain = classes.that(not(belongToAnyOf(Main.class)));
rule.check(allExceptMain);
```

Comment: I tried it and it does not work: can you check here please?
https://gist.github.com/lsoares/a3e725a08f185cb1564bdc477c706fd5

Comment: It looks like the method calls don't happen in `users.WebAppConfig` directly, but in the class `users.WebAppConfig$javalinApp$1$2`. (Looks like the class structure generated by Kotlin?) I updated my answer with an example for `belongToAnyOf`.

Comment: still get this: https://gist.github.com/lsoares/d98ee5f789a8f75ca3d5210e6ee9967e

Comment: I edited my question to add the source code if you can take a look that'd be great. the project has no deps. just clone and run the tests. thanks

Answer (score 2):

How about something like this:

```
.ignoreDependency(fullNameMatching("users.WebAppConfig"), alwaysTrue())
```

Comment: I edited my question to add the source code if you can take a look that'd be great. the project has no deps. just clone and run the tests. thanks

Comment: I made it work with:
.ignoreDependency(fullNameMatching("users.WebAppConfig"), alwaysTrue())

"fullNameMatching" predicate is defined in HasName. You have something similar for types in HasType.

Comment: I tried that and it becomes green; problem is that now I can't make it fail in any way.. I tried to break the layer rules and it never becomes red.

Comment: that's weird, i tried it in one of my projects in java and it worked just fine. maybe it has something to do with the integration with kotlin?

Answer (score 0):

Another possibility would be to explicitly declare the part of your source code that is in charge of starting the application ("users" package) as a bona fide layer and integrate it into your rules. After all, that's how you want your source code to work, so i wonder if making it an exception is the way to go.